# Given 2 vector magnitudes and the angle between them, find the endpoint

Tags: python, numpy, math, vector, physics

I have a vector AB and vector BC in 3D. I have the magnitudes of these 2 vectors as well . I also know the angle between  vector AB and vector BC. Moreover, I know the coordinates of A and B as well.

I want to find the coordinates of C.

To be more specific, for a vector AB of fixed length, I want to construct a lot of vectors with different magnitudes and fixed angle between AB and the 'to be constructed vectors' with the information provided above.

One way I know of is to find x y and z coordinates of the endpoint C but in 3D 2 angles are required and I only have one, so I am unable to think of a solution.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: There is no unique solution. The locus of C is a circle, and there are infinite solutions. Also, this does not seem to be a programming problem.

Comment: I may be better to ask your question on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. Actually I am trying to code this to construct a tree structure. 
I have a vector and I want to construct another vector from it's endpoint by providing 1 angle and a length and then find it's endpoint.

Comment: As already mentioned before, and I second it, there is no unique point C in 3D that satisfies your conditions, but a whole circle of these.

Comment: Hmm thank you so much for your clarifications. I was wondering if there is any way where the coordinate system can be changed. Could there be a way to deconstruct the 1 angle I have into 2 angles where I get the elevation and azimuth by some formula that converts a coordinate system. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Your problem does not have sufficient constraints. Unless you restrict where C can lie in some way (e.g. a specific plane), there is no unique solution for C, irrespective of the coordinate system and representation used.

Comment: @coder1122 Suppose you find such a point `C` in 3D. Then rotate everything by an arbitrary angle around the line `AB`. All lengths and angles are preserved, but `C` will move to a new position `C'` which satisfies all the same requirements. So, as noted in the previous comments, there is no unique solution to the problem unless you add another constraint.

Answer (score 0):

if you want an algorithm that selects one of the infinitely many such points, maybe the following algorithm would work for you:

```py
import numpy as np

def frame_rotation(v):
    i = np.argmin(v) 
    E = np.zeros(3)
    E[i] = 1
    U = np.empty((3,3), dtype=float)
    U[0, :] = v
    U[2, :] = np.cross(v, E)
    U[2, :] = U[2, :] / np.linalg.norm(U[2, :])
    U[1, :] = np.cross(U[2, :], U[0, :]) 
    return U.T

def find_a_point_C(A, B, length_BC, angle):
    AB = B - A
    length_AB = np.linalg.norm(B-A)
    AB = AB / length_AB
    angle = angle * np.pi/180    
    C = np.array([np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle), 0])
    C = length_BC * C
    C[0] = C[0] + length_AB
    U = frame_rotation(AB)
    return U.dot(C) + A

def cos_angle(v,w):
    return v.dot(w)/ (np.linalg.norm(v)*np.linalg.norm(w))


A = np.array([1,3,2])
B = np.array([2,7,7])
length_BC = 3
angle = 60 # degrees

C = find_a_point_C(A, B, length_BC, angle)

print(C)

# test for correctness
print(np.linalg.norm(C-B))
print(cos_angle(B-A,C-B))
print(cos_angle(B-A,C-B) - np.cos(angle*np.pi/180))
```